# Is restlet + simple combination suitable for production environment?

Tags: restlet

I have a processing application which accepts REST requests and doesn't include a GUI such as a web front-end. Processing is light but the number of requests is quite high (*more than 10,000 requests in a second*).

I wonder if Restlet + Simple combination is appropriate for this scenario or do I have to use a Java EE edition?

Does anyone have experience with Restlet + Simple combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Restlet, you have the concept of server connectors. This means that you could choose the appropriate connector for your need in a JSE environment (edition `jse`). It's clear that the default connector isn't suitable for production (it was even not present within org.restlet in the last version 2.3). So you can choose to use the Jetty extension (simply put the extension `org.restlet.ext.jetty` in your classpath - no impact in your application code) to use it as transport. We use successfully this approach in production (with load balancy in front of this) for one of our application.

If you don't want to handle load balancing, ... by yourself, you could prefer to use an application server to let it handle this.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks thierry. As I understand from your answer there is no difference between SE and EE editions in http side or from scalability view point. They both are suitable for production. However, EE edition (servlet container) provides some facilities out-of-the-box like balancing, clustering, ... right??

Comment: Yes, you're right ;-) You can notice that changing from one to the other has almost no impact for your application (not at the Restlet level - application, server resources, ...). The only impact is if you want to or use managed services of the application server (managed connection pools, ...).